# Retrieve the Session ID From SugarCRM

Tags: session, sugarcrm, sessionid, suitecrm, seamless-login

I want an external URL in the Opportunity DetailView that includes the current session ID (like the one you get when using the SugarCRM API and authenticating) and the ID of the Opportunity. This link will go to an external application that will show a summary of data.

How can I retrieve the Session ID from within PHP in SugarCRM?

I know I can add a new file to add custom code to the page template:

```
SuiteCRM\custom\modules\Opportunities\views\view.detail.php
```

Below is an example of what I want:

```
<?php

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.detail.php');

class OpportunitiesViewDetail extends ViewDetail
{
    function OpportunitiesViewList()
    {
        parent::ViewDetail();
    }

    function preDisplay()
    {
        echo "<a href='http://localhost/Index/session-key/opportunity id/'>Summary View</a>";
        parent::preDisplay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **session_id()**.

```
<?php

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.detail.php');

class OpportunitiesViewDetail extends ViewDetail {

    function OpportunitiesViewDetail(){
        parent::ViewDetail();
    }

    function display() {
        $session_id = session_id();

        echo "<a href='http://localhost/Index/" . $session_id . "/" . $this->bean->id . "'>Summary View</a>";

        parent::display();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that. Unfortunately, when the SOAP API validates the session using `seamless_login(sessionId)` the session is expired immediately in the CRM and the SOAP API says it is invalid as well. Have you tried this? It seems the session of the CRM and SOAP are independent. Which makes sense that you can never get in your own way.